# Saying “and” with two different clauses?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, syntax

I’ve seen a few threads about saying “and” but I’m not sure what to do if there’s a time element in the second clause.

For example, I want to say “I just woke up and I work later.”

Would that be 「今起きたし後で働く。」？
Or 「今起きたそして働く。」？

(I’m wondering if 仕事がある would be more fitting)

Comment: Unfortunately “I just woke up and I work later.” doesn't sound very natural to me. 'Later' and 'just' don't play well together. May be a better example would be "I just woke up and I have to go to work in 5 minutes".

Comment: i used it as an example because i was trying to say it to someone, hahaha. they asked how my day was. i consider it more explanatory so i might want to add んだ but it sounds perfectly natural to me in english since i do speak like this

Comment: Dunno, that sounds unnatural in English to me too...

Comment: What did you mean by 'later' here? Did you mean 'after a bit'? Or like after a few hours?

Comment: after a few hours

Comment: i’m thinking my sentence would make more sense if i said “i just woke up but later i work”

Comment: So what you really need is "but" rather than "and"...I believe you know how to say "but"?

Comment: you’re right and i do, “but” certainly is much easier to try to translate!

Answer (score 1):

日本語として自然な表現をすると、次のような感じになるかと思います。一部、意訳を含みます。

> “I just woke up and I work later.”

今起きたところなので、もう少ししたら仕事に出かけます。(If later means few minutes. Sometimes 「もう少し」means more longer time, like one hour later or so, but it depends on 文脈 or situations.)

しばらくしたら仕事に出かけます。(same as or a little longer than 「もう少し」)

or

今起きた所です。何時間かしたら仕事に出かけます。(if later means few hours)

> "I just woke up and I have to go to work in 5 minutes"

今起きばかりですが、あと5分で仕事に出かけなくてはいけません。

In the first sentence "and" can be replaced with「なので」(reason), and in the second one "and" is used for 「が」(including some negative meaning) as later part contains negative sense.

文脈によって、"and" の意味が変わってきますので、そこに当てはまりそうな単語に置き換えてしまえば問題ないかと思います。

---

NB: about「もう少し」

日本語の「もう少し」が表現する時間は、かなりあいまいです。
数分のこともあれば、1時間あるいは数時間を意味する場合もあります。

例えば、日本のQ&Aサイトで、このような質問の例がありますので、参考にされるとよいかと思います。

From Q&A site
https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1339405173

> Q:もう少ししたら帰るね。の、｢もう少し｣ってどれくらいですか？？
>
> A:私の感覚では、大人なら１時間、子供なら３０分、という時間感覚になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 「もう少ししたら」と訳すと“After a bit”などといった感じで、意味が変わってきます。Later＝１０時間後などといった可能性もありますし

Comment: @VVayfarer そこは質問へのコメントの内容なども読んだ上での意訳です。

Comment: 意訳ならかっこ書きかなにかでそれを表すべきではないでしょうか。あのままでは誤った認識を与えてしまう可能性もあるわけですから

Comment: @VVayfarer 逐語訳が必要だとお考えでしたら、ご自身で解答されるのがよいかと思います。質問者自身が、原文が変だと認識した上で、ニュアンス的に近い表現だと書いているのですから…

Comment: それが、自分では変だと思っていないそうです。「it sounds perfectly natural to me in english since i do speak like this」と言っていますし。それにどうやら「数時間後」という意味でのLaterだったそうなので、やはりこの翻訳は意訳として成立するとは思えません。私が回答するかどうかは別として、誤った翻訳は正すべきです。

Comment: Uh, it seems a little rude to insist that much for someone to change their answer... I know you’re trying to improve answer/site quality, but this probably has negative side effects from the kindness and community building aspects ^^.